# Sublime Text 2 command line not working after Mavericks install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sublimetext2, osx-mavericks, bash

I've ready through other threads on Stack Overflow and despite my efforts the issue doesn't seem to resolve. Since installing OS X Mavericks I'm not able to open Sublime Text 2 from the command line.

I've tried following these guidelines:

http://benkwok.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/setup-sublime-text-2-on-osx-mavericks-for-ruby-on-rails/

When I run this from the terminal Sublime pops up so that's good:
http://benkwok.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/setup-sublime-text-2-on-osx-mavericks-for-ruby-on-rails/

I've added these lines to the bottom of my bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH↲
export EDITOR='subl -w'
```

However, when I try to run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

from the command line I get:

```
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: Gemfile: command not found
```

When I try to subl . from inside a folder with files in it, I get the following error:

```
-bash: subl: command not found
```

So, my bash_profile is obviously configured wrong for Mavericks. Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with that blog post. First, the symlink is pointing to the wrong target if you're using Sublime Text 2. It should be

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

as the application's name is `Sublime Text 2.app`. Sublime 3 is named `Sublime Text.app`. Make sure you run

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/subl
```

to delete the old (incorrect) symlink before making the new one.

Next, there is an invalid character in the `export PATH` command. It should be

```
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

without the `↲` character at the end.

Make these changes, exit Terminal and restart, and you should be able to run `subl .` to open a folder, or `subl filename` to open individual files.